# How to auto expand all JPanel's by default

Tags: jquery, jpanel

I am using [JPanel](https://sites.google.com/site/jqpanel/demo) I want to auto expand all the panels on page load, how can i achieve it?

Sample JPanel Code

```
<div title="Title1" class="class">
    content here....
</div>
<div title="Title2" class="class">
    content here....
</div>

$('.class').jPanel({
    'effect'    : 'fade',
    'speed'     : 'slow',
    'easing'    : 'swing'
});
```

My code

```
$('#contentHolder).empty();
$('<div>')
.html('<div >'+productname+'</div>'+panels)     
    .appendTo('#contentHolder').delay(10).queue(function(){
        $('.class').jPanel({
            'effect'    : 'fade',
            'speed'     : 'slow',
            'easing'    : 'swing'
        });
   });

$('.class').jPanel({         
    'effect'    : 'fade',
    'speed'     : 'slow',         
    'easing'    : 'swing'     
}).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger a click event after the call to jPanel:

```
$('.class')
    .jPanel({
        'effect'    : 'fade',
        'speed'     : 'slow',
        'easing'    : 'swing'
    })
    .children('h3') // or .children('.head')
    .trigger('click');
```

d.

Comment: I tried your example, but it is not working, see my updated question

Comment: Changed the code a bit. The click event should occur on the heading (tested and working).

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the jPanel version to 1.4.0, now you can specify the open by default param to achieve this as below e.g.:

```
$('selector').jPanel({
    "defaultOpen"   :  true
});
```

Hope this helps